# How do I address an ETag Error on Removing a resource from collection with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-docs-api, google-apps-script

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#removing_a_resource_from_collection), an If-Match eTag isn't required to remove an item from a collection, yet I'm getting the following error:

```
"Request failed for returned code 403. Server response:
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
  <error>
    <domain>GData</domain>
    <code>matchHeaderRequired</code>
    <location type='header'>If-Match|If-None-Match</location>
    <internalReason>If-Match or If-None-Match header or entry etag attribute required</internalReason>
  </error>
</errors>"
```

What am I missing?  And if I did actually wish to trash the resource, how and where would I specify the If-Match tag?  I tried sticking a "If-Match:"*"" in my options just in case, but without success.

Is this related to this Python client library error? [DeleteResource from Google Docs with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940578/deleteresource-from-google-docs-with-python)

My Apps Script code is as follows:

```
function deleteResourceFromCollection_(originCollectionId,resourceId) {
  var options = buildDeleteOptions_();

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(DOC_API_URL+ACTIVE_USER+"/private/full/"+originCollectionId+"/contents/"+resourceId, options); 
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Build URLFetchApp Delete Options
//////////////////////////////////////////////
function buildDeleteOptions_() {

  return {
    method : "delete",
    headers : {"GData-Version": "3.0"},
    oAuthServiceName: "google",
    oAuthUseToken: "always",
    };
}
```

Comment: Did you put the If-Match: in the headers?

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax for options is:

```
function buildDeleteOptions_() {

  return {
    method : "delete",
    headers : {"GData-Version": "3.0", "If-Match":"*"},
    oAuthServiceName: "google",
    oAuthUseToken: "always",
    };
}
```